# Hourly Set Report in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a daily reporting system in place which shows the number of calls made by a particular telecaller in a day. And it works well.

I'd like to bifurcate it further into hours for e.g 9-10, 10-11 and so on.

The current mysql code is this. Please excuse imperfect code, I'm a self learner and have learnt what I have from Stackexchange.

```
    SELECT
comments.hrname,
IF((HOUR(comments.date))= '9', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `9-10`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '10', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `10-11`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '11', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `11-12`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '12', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `12-13`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '13', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `13-14`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '14', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `14-15`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '15', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `15-16`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '16', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `16-17`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '17', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `17-18`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '18', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `18-19`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '19', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `19-20`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '20', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `20-21`,
IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '21', COUNT(comments.Outcome),'') AS `21-22`
FROM
comments
WHERE
DATE(comments.date) = DATE(NOW()) AND
MONTH(comments.date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND
YEAR(comments.date) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY
comments.hrname
```

And the outcome I get is this:

Where am I going wrong?

P.S This is an internal software for approx 10 users, primarily designed to eradicate shared excel use, so SQL Injection etc is not really a concern AFAIK.

Any help would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your query does, is putting the `COUNT()` in the column you want, but it actually counts every row. There's only one condition, where `COUNT()` distinguishes between "to count" or "not to count". And that is, that when you `COUNT(*)` every row is counted, no matter what. When you `COUNT(column_name)`, it counts only the rows that are not `NULL`. But that just aside.

What you actually want to do is this:

```
SUM(IF((HOUR(comments.date)) = '9', 1, 0)) AS `9-10`,
```

Another note:
When you do

```
WHERE
DATE(comments.date) = DATE(NOW()) AND
MONTH(comments.date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND
YEAR(comments.date) = YEAR(NOW())
```

the comparison for month and year is unnecessary, since this is already covered in `DATE()`.

An even better way to do this is actually doing this:

```
WHERE comments.date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59')
```

or

```
WHERE comments.date >= CURDATE() 
AND comments.date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This is because MySQL can't use an index on a column (if there is any), when you use a function on this column.

Comment: Instead of `NOW()`, use `CURDATE()`.

Comment: More compact:  SUM(HOUR(comments.date) = 9) AS `9-10`

Comment: @RickJames You're right with `CURDATE()`, don't know how I missed that, edited my answer now accordingly. I didn't write the more compact version so that it's clearer for OP how it works. But thanks for the hints.